# ngStyle parser error for giving background color

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a table in which I want to give background color to some rows. The condition is that if the first data element of the row (which is going to be an icon) is archived icon, then I have to give the whole row a gray background color.
The HTML code is as:

```html
<tr class='flow-row' [bSelectableRow]="item">
  <td>
    <ng-container *ngFor='let icon of getIconForFlow(item);'>
      <class='flow-icon' [icon]="icon.icon" [title]="icon.title">
        </bt-icon>
    </ng-container>
  </td>
  <td> Name </td>
</tr>
```

I tried something like this:

```html
<tr class='flow-row' [bSelectableRow]="item">
  <td>
    <ng-container *ngFor='let icon of getIconForFlow(item);'>
      <class='flow-icon' [icon]="icon.icon" [title]="icon.title">
        </bt-icon>
    </ng-container>
  </td>
  <td> Name </td>
</tr>
```

But I am getting a parser error with this: Bindings cannot contain assignments.
Same was the error if I tried giving `ngClass` instead of `ngStyle`.

Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Angular has issues when the template contains some functions. You can create a method in your .ts file that returns a value for the background color. Replace it with `getIconForFlow(item).some(icon => icon.icon === 'archived') ? '#ccc' : ''` in your template.